# Prove: If H and G/H are totally disconnected then G is also totally disconnected

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, connectedness, quotient-spaces

Let $G$ be a topological group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$. If $H$ and $G/H$ are totally disconnected, then $G$ is also totally disconnected.

With 'totally disconnected' we mean the every connected component of a given topological group has only one element.

My proof:

Let $R \subseteq G$ be a connected subset of $G$. We want to show that $R$ has only one element. (Can we suppose that $e \in R$??). We suppose that $e \in R$. Let $q$ be the quotient map $q: G \rightarrow G/H$. Then $q(R) \subseteq G/H$ is connected, because $q$ is continuous. We know that $G/H$ is totally disconnected, so $q(R)$ has only one element in $G/H$ and that should be $H$, i.e. $q(R)=H$, hence $R \subseteq  H$. $H$ is also totally disconnected, so $R$ contains only one element and we are done.

Is this correct? Can someone look at this? I am thankful for every kind of tips.

Comment: Since translation by $g \in G$ is an homeomorphism, you can suppose $e \in R$, yes.

Comment: It's implied here that $H$ is a closed subgroup. Otherwise the quotient map $q$ would not be continuous.

Comment: But its easy to prove that the quotient map q:X → X/~ is always continuous, if X/~ has the quotient topology, so your post should be wrong, i think.